# Unable to start program, cannot find the file specified, Visual Studio 11

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2012

I'm working off of a fresh install of VS 11 Beta, on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.  When I try to debug, it gives me this error message.

"Unable to start program 'C:\Users\myname\documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\Project1\Debug\Project1.exe"

I'm almost entirely sure it isn't a problem with my code--it works fine on online compilers, making me think that it's an issue with how I'm saving it.  Just in case, here it is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
printf("Hello, world!\n");
return 0;
}
```

My process for creating the project/file is to create a new empty Visual C++ project, then a .cpp file, write my code, save it as a .c inside of the first folder I'm prompted with, within the projects folder, and then try to debug.

What am I doing wrong, here?  I know that the debug folder is empty, but I can't figure out how to create the .exe file that should reside in it.

NB: I'm rather new to programming.  If answers could be phrased in babyspeak, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there could be a number of things wrong. However, based on your description of making a ccp file *and* a c file, I'm betting that it's a problem in your VS 11 project rather than the code itself. My guess would be that either the c file didn't get included in your project (check the Solution Explorer) or that you have the main (or _tmain) function defined in both the cpp and the c files, which will make the linker issue an error.

There are a bunch of "Hello World" tutorials online for VS 2010 and earlier, but there don't seem to be many for VS 11 Beta yet. You may want to take a look at the 2010 versions. I found [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr822bJuzmc) that you may want to check out.

Comment: How exactly would I check the Solution Explorer?  I'm not quite sure what you mean.  
The video is great.  Thanks.  I'd still like to figure out why what I was doing wasn't working, though.

Comment: The VS interface can differ based on how you have it configured, so I'll refer to the setup from the linked tutorial. On the left of the main window should be a view labeled "Solution Explorer." If you don't see that window, you should be able to open it via the View menu. This window displays the files in your project, which is what the compiler will generate your program from. Expand the "Source Files" folder and make sure your c file appears there.

Comment: Hmmm.  I've got nothing in there.  I'll try to fix that.

Comment: Hah!  Got it.  File>Move (filename) into>(foldername)
I don't know why that's there, but that fixes the problem.  It runs just fine, now.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output directory. And you can also set manually an output direcotry to save the built exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this problem was from May but I thought I would answer with a solution that worked for me:

I was creating a `.cpp` file in a blank project and was getting a similar error. I noticed that the file had a name but was not showing the extension `.cpp`. I added the extension to the file (`ex3.18.cpp`) and did not get the `.exe` error again.

I don't know if that makes sense with your issue but I worked on this for two days uninstalling and reinstalling VS 11, and this was what finally worked.